# Why am I having Issues with Separating Rows in a Dataframe?

Tags: r

I'm having an issue with separating rows in a dataframe that I'm working in.

In my dataframe, there's a column called officialIndices that I want to separate the rows by. This column stores a list of numbers act as indexes to indicate which rows have the same data. For example: indices 2:3 means that rows 2:3 have the same data.

Here is the code that I am working with.

```
offices_list <- data_google$offices
offices_JSON <- toJSON(offices_list)
offices_from_JSON <-
  separate_rows(fromJSON(offices_JSON), officialIndices, convert = TRUE)
```

This is what my offices_list frame looks like
[image: This is what my offices_list frame looks like]

This is what it looks like after I try to separate the rows
[image: After separating the rows]

My code works fine when it has indices 2:3 since there is a difference of 1. However on indices like 7:10, it separates the rows as 7 and 10 instead of doing 7, 8, 9, 10, which is how I want it do be done. How would I get my code to separate the rows like this?

Output of dput(head(offices_list))

```
structure(list(position = c("President of the United States", 
"Vice-President of the United States", "United States Senate", 
"Governor", "Mayor", "Auditor"), divisionId = c("ocd-division/country:us", 
"ocd-division/country:us", "ocd-division/country:us/state:or", 
"ocd-division/country:us/state:or", "ocd-division/country:us/state:or/place:portland", 
"ocd-division/country:us/state:or/place:portland"), levels = list(
    "country", "country", "country", "administrativeArea1", NULL, 
    NULL), roles = list(c("headOfState", "headOfGovernment"), 
    "deputyHeadOfGovernment", "legislatorUpperBody", "headOfGovernment", 
    NULL, NULL), officialIndices = list(0L, 1L, 2:3, 4L, 5L, 
    6L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You will get better & faster help if you include a sample of your data. Otherwise, helpers will either have to generate fake data on their own or re-type from your screenshot. Please edit your question to include the output of `dput(head(offices_list))`.

Comment: Just added the output @JonSpring

Comment: Also, dput(head(offices_list)) only takes the first 6 rows of the data. Row 7-10 is where the problem is happening @JonSpring

Comment: Fair point. FYI, `dput(head(offices_list, 10))` will include first 10 rows. Added solution that seems to work for wider `officialIndices` ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. I expect it will work for further rows too, since I tested for ranges greater than two in `officialIndices`.

First I extracted the start and end rows, and used their difference to determine how many rows are needed. Then `tidyr::uncount()` will add that many copies.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
data_sep <- data %>%
  separate(officialIndices, into = c("start", "end"), sep = ":") %>%
  # Use 1 row, and more if "end" is defined and larger than "start"
  mutate(rows = 1 + if_else(is.na(end), 0, as.numeric(end) - as.numeric(start))) %>%
  uncount(rows)
```